# Character encoding for PrintWriter.print(int)

Tags: java, character-encoding

The documentation for the [`PrintWriter.print(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#print%28int%29) method says:

> Prints an integer. The string produced by `String.valueOf(int)` is translated into bytes **according to the platform's default character encoding**, and these bytes are written in exactly the manner of the `write(int)` method.

Is it really true that it uses the platforms default character encoding? Is the documentation wrong?

The documented behaviour makes no sense if the `PrintWriter` delegates to another `Writer` (as created by the constructor [`PrintWriter(Writer)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.io.Writer%29)). The claimed behaviour would be surprising for the case of a `PrinterWriter` that was constructed using a named character encoding (using the constructor [`PrintWriter(File, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29)).

Comment: I think it's just a lazy copy and paste from the `PrintStream` docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is wrong, at least for the Oracle implementation of PrintWriter, which does the following:

```
public void print(int i) {
    write(String.valueOf(i));
}
```

So, no conversion to byte is done, and `write(int)` is not called. BTW, `write(int)` writes a character, not a byte.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.

Following the source code of PrintWriter.write(int) it ends up mapping to the following abstract method:

```
abstract public void write(char cbuf[], int off, int len) throws IOException;
```

Checking one case where this method is implemented OutputStreamWriter, one may pass in a specific charset to use and in that case the implementation of that abstract method will use that char set and not the platforms.

Thus the documentation must have been considering the expected default behavior back in the day, but it does not cover how different subclasses actually behave today.  Thus the doc could use being updated now.  Raise a bug request with Oracle.